# Canvas font being ignored when explicitly assigned

Tags: javascript, canvas, fonts

I am drawing a text on canvas. Issue is ctx.font = font gets completely ignored and sets default to 10px sans-serif.
Here's my function.

```
function drawResTexts(num) {
                    var num = num || "";
                    var font = (resTxtStyle["font-style"+num] != 
undefined ? resTxtStyle["font-style"+num] : "normal") + " " + resTxtStyle["font-size"+num] + "px " + resTxtStyle["font"+num];

                    ctx.font = font; // This line has no effect whatsoever

                    ctx.textAlign = resTxtStyle["align"+num] || "left";
                    var txtArr = resTxt.split("\n");

                    for (var i = 0; i < txtArr.length; i++) {
                        if (resTxtStyle["stroke"+num] != undefined) {
                            var stroke = resTxtStyle["stroke"+num].split(" ");
                            ctx.strokeStyle = stroke[1];
                            ctx.lineWidth = Number(stroke[0]) * 2;
                            ctx.strokeText(txtArr[i], resTxtStyle["pos"+num][0], resTxtStyle["pos"+num][1]);
                        }
                        ctx.fillStyle = resTxtStyle["color"+num];
                        ctx.fillText(txtArr[i], resTxtStyle["pos"+num][0], resTxtStyle["pos"+num][1] + i * (resTxtStyle["line-height"+num] || 0));
                    }
                }
```

Then i call this function using drawText();

font variable is `"regular 45px Georgia"`

Here's my resTxtStyle obj

```
resTxtStyle = {
           "align": "center",
            "font": "Georgia",
            "font-size": "45",
            "font-style": "regular",
            "color": "#FFFF4C",
            "stroke": "2 #000"
}
```

Can somebody please help ?

I saw a similar issue here but here - http://www.tenpay.tech/questions/2162612/html-5-canvas-font-being-ignored But here canvas.getContext was being called again that was resetting the font, but there is no such case in mine.

Help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 3):

As it turns out, font should be "normal 45px Georgia". Its weird because every graphic software uses "regular" for font style.
May be someone will get help with this.

Comment: Yes canvas `font` property expects a valid CSS `font` shorthand value, where *standard*  `font-weight` is called `normal`, which is also a quite frequent name for what is also called *regular* or *plain*. Note that you can also use the [TrueType numerical weight scale](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight#Common_weight_name_mapping), if you don't like the names. And your assertion that *"every graphic software uses "regular""* is mislead: They use the name the font designers gave to them. e.g on my osx default *Tahoma* is *normal*, and for *Savoye LET* it's *plain*.